# German/Swedish dictionary to download as a text file

Tags: dictionary, german, online-resources, swedish

I am looking for a dictionary that I can download as a text file which specifies the grammatical gender of nouns in both languages.

Basically, I would like something like:
https://archive.org/details/svensktyskordbok00hoppuoft

In a format which I can automatically parse.
I am only interested in nouns so a partial dictionary would do too.

Many thanks!!

Comment: @hippietrail, thanks for the comment but it is not what I need. I need German-Swedish (or Swedish-German). Something like that: Arzt (m) : Läkare (u)               Thanks